# How to mark a entity as changed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

say I've a entity class `user`. Now in that class, I want to do:

```
partial class user{
    public void save()
    {
       using (ent e = new ent())
       {
           var res = (from u in e.user where u.name == name select u).first();
           res = someOtherUserObject;
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
}
```

- Q1: Is this possible ?
- Q2: Is it possible to retrive a entity and marking as if it is changed without actually changing it?

---

The question may have been already answered but I could not find the link.

Answer (score 1):

> Q2: Is it possible to retrive a entity and marking as if it is changed without actually changing it?

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx):

```
 using (var context = new BloggingContext())
    {
        var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);

        context.Entry(blog).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified = true;

        // Use a string for the property name
        context.Entry(blog).Property("Name").IsModified = true;
    }
```

Comment: You can do this to entire entry: `context.Entry(blog).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`